# Displaying a Random String on Button Click

Tags: javascript, json, random, generator, quote

My goal is to have a button that when clicked displays a random quote. I have already created a JSON object to store my quotes and written a function to randomly select and print a quote from the object.

The HTML snippet - button (Bootstrap etc.)

```
<div class="row" id="quotebox">
  <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-default" onclick ="randomQuote()"type="submit">Hit Me Baby One More Time</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JSON object storing 5 quotes

```
var quotesList = [{
    quote: "Planting popcorn does not produce more popcorn",
    person: "Farmer Ted"
}, {
    quote: "White whale, bad whale",
    person: "Confucious (Moby Dick)"
}, {
    quote: "Use the strobe function to disorientate your attacker",
    person: "Flashlight"
}, {
    quote: "Apply liberally to your erogenous zones",
    person: "Spice Bomb"
}, {
    quote: "Help me, I'm bleaching",
    person: "The Great Barrier Reef"
}];
```

Finally, the function to print the random quote (triggered by onClick)

```
function randomQuote() {
  var listLength =  Object.keys(quoteList).length;
  var randVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * listLength);
  document.write(quotesList[randVal]);
}
```

The two snippets above comprise my entire JavaScript code.

Comment: Best title ever. No seriously avoid noise, in text and title, stuff that doesn't benefit the reader, cursing probably falls into that category.

Comment: `var listLength = quoteList.length;` is all you need for the length. And you can't use `document.write()` if you want to be able to click more than once.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful yup. Plus the title was probably meant to say `random quote generator`, not `random code generator`.  Shows how much attention the question asker is paying - no wonder it has problems with simple coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed JS. The main problem was that you were using `Object.keys(quoteList).length` to get the length of `quoteList` even though it is just a simple array. Additionally, you were using `document.write`, which is generally considered to be bad practice. I replaced it by setting `document.getElementById('quotebox').innerHTML` to a string with the quote and author. Finally, you were writing the whole quote object to the screen instead of accessing the individual attributes of the quote object and constructing a string from them.

```
var $quoteBox = document.getElementById('quotebox');

var quotesList = [
  {
    quote: "Planting popcorn does not produce more popcorn",
    person: "Farmer Ted"
  }, {
    quote: "White whale, bad whale",
    person: "Confucious (Moby Dick)"
  }, {
    quote: "Use the strobe function to disorientate your attacker",
    person: "Flashlight"
  }, {
    quote: "Apply liberally to your erogenous zones",
    person: "Spice Bomb"
  }, {
    quote: "Help me, I'm bleaching",
    person: "The Great Barrier Reef"
  }
];

function randomQuote() {
  var randIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesList.length);
  var randQuote = quotesList[randIdx];
  $quoteBox.innerHTML = "\"" + randQuote.quote + "\" - " + randQuote.person;
}
```

Comment: Downvoter care to explain what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Upvoted to bring it back from the negative side! :-)

Comment: @pzp, Thanks for your help and explanation. I had to tweak the HTML so that the quote would not replace the button after the first click, but now have it working as I want. I will have to read up more on document.getElementById and innerHTML